# Join on table with one-to-many relationship producing weird results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am trying to pull payment information, which is on a different table, for all orders that have an onlineorderid within a specific date range. But I'm getting inconsistent results as well as a lot of duplicates.

I tried to perform a simple join between tblpayments and tblorders but that did not work. I believe the issue is that tblpayments has a one-to-many relationship with tblorders as there can be multiple payments on the same orderid. Keep in mind this is MYSql 5.6

Here is the query I tried and ultimately did not work.

```
SELECT 
    pmtorderid,
    pmtorderdate AS 'Date',
    pmtamt,
    pmtchgtip,
    pmtident1,
    o.ordonlineorderid
FROM
    tblorders o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblpayments p ON p.pmtorderid = o.orderid
WHERE
    pmttype = 3
        AND o.ordonlineorderid IS NOT NULL
        AND DATE(PmtOrderDate) BETWEEN '2019-04-22' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY PmtOrderID , PmtOrderDate
```

When I query tblorders with the WHERE clause below I get about 70+ records, which is accurate, but when I use this clause with the JOIN I get thousands of records which I know is incorrect.

```
WHERE pmttype = 3 
    AND o.ordonlineorderid IS NOT NULL 
    AND DATE(PmtOrderDate) BETWEEN '2019-04-22' AND '2019-04-30'
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `GROUP BY` in your query?

Comment: Shouldn't ```PmtOrderDate``` in your where clause be ```pmtorderdate```? Case is important with column names.

Comment: Google how to use `GROUP BY`.  It serves no purpose here.

Comment: I just added it out of curiosity, because my original query was producing thousands of records. Using group by reduced it down to a few hundred, which was still wrong, but I left it as is since it was slightly less wrong if that makes sense and I wasn't sure what else to try at that point. Probably a poor decision on my part, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got your left join logic confused. Using a left join and adding where conditions for the left table will return every row in the right table and some rows will have a match in the left table.

Based on your where condition, I think you only want rows that are in BOTH tables and in that case, change your join to an INNER JOIN.

Here's a link to learn a little bit about Left vs Inner join:
http://a4academics.com/tutorials/24-sql-tutorial/729-difference-between-inner-join-and-left-join

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, there can be multiple payments for an order, and possibly a single payment for multiple orders.  With this being the case, there is need to join on some other field(s), potentially through additional tables.  Having no knowledge of your schema we can offer no specific solution.

Comment: Thanks, I found another field to join the tables on and that appears to have fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a left outer join, use a join. This will eliminate rows in tblorders with no matching rows in tblpayments. Also, column names are case sensitive, make sure their spelling (including case) are correct.

```
SELECT 
    p.pmtorderid,
    p.pmtorderdate AS 'Date',
    p.pmtamt,
    p.pmtchgtip,
    p.pmtident1,
    o.ordonlineorderid
FROM tblorders o
JOIN tblpayments p 
    ON p.pmtorderid = o.orderid
WHERE
    p.pmttype = 3
    AND o.ordonlineorderid IS NOT NULL
    AND DATE(p.pmtorderdate) BETWEEN '2019-04-22' AND '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY pmtorderid, pmtorderdate
```